# More stable spatial sort using Shapely's within?

Tags: python, shapely, sorting, within

I was trying to use a modified version of the [spatial sorting method illustrated in shapely's documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.within), using only polygons exteriors (so that I can detect if a polygon lies inside another polygon hole), and it didn't always work.

To investigate this, I went back to the documentation example:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon


class Within(object):
    def __init__(self, o):
        self.o = o

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.o.within(other.o)


# a is inside b that is inside c; d is far away
a = Point(2, 2)
b = Polygon([[1, 1], [1, 3], [3, 3], [3, 1]])
c = Polygon([[0, 0], [0, 4], [4, 4], [4, 0]])
d = Point(-1, -1)

sorted_feat = [d, c, c, b, a]
assert sorted_feat == sorted([c, a, d, b, c], key=Within, reverse=True)
```

so far so good.
But when I tried to change the order of the initial list, the result changed:

```py
shuffled = [b, a, c, d, c]
# I was expecting the same sorted list...
assert sorted_feat != sorted(shuffled, key=Within, reverse=True)
# ... but I got this instead.
assert [c, b, a, d, c] == (sorted(shuffled, key=Within, reverse=True))
```

I understand that this is because of how `sorted()` works, that is guaranteed to be stable (items with the same key appears in the original order) and that the `within()` method obviously returns false if the two geometry are apart from each other, but I was expecting that at least the "relative order" would be kept (that is, to always have `[c, c, b, a]` order and `d` randomly inserted).

Is there a solution to this? How can I group the geometries and get the order that I need?

Comment: Update: I found another solution for my root problem (I needed to create multipolygons from a series of rings, and I found out that the rings were compound paths - ccw direction = filled, cw = hole). I would still like to implement the algorithm for the question, though.